# String as only private field for new class

Tags: java, string, constructor, immutability, private

General question here: If I'm making a new class, and it's only private field is a string, can I do something like `this.privateString = argumentIn;` in the constructor to set that private field? I'm just weary since I'm not good with the whole referencing part of java.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Compiled, but I had to add a couple methods at the time before real testing would've been viable, but turns out it was right >.<

Comment: So if it compiled you can do it. That test is a lot quicker than posting on forums ;-)

Comment: The point is, you can reference a local object, but once it goes out of scope, then you're not referencing that object anymore. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing that on accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, and thus the definition of a private field being only accessible from within the class itself.

And as a tip, without any accessors, this may render your objects of this class mostly useless.

Comment: I plan on using .charAt to pick out different parts of the string. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: You can even do this if your private field is also final.

Comment: Indeed, if you've no intention of changing the field, it is a good idea to declare it as `final` for both stylistic and technical reasons.  (The latter is too hard to explain in a comment, but it helps when instances of the class might be created and used by different threads.)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. Consider this example. I have added some basic defensive copying practice.

```
/**
* MyClass is an immutable class, since there is no way to change
* its state after construction.
*/

public final class MyClass{

private final String myString;

public MyClass(String myString){
   this.myString = myString;
}

 /**
  * Returns an immutable object. String is immutable.
  *
  */

public String getMyString(){
   return myString;
}

//no need to provide a setter to keep myString as immutable after initial state
}
```

Consider reading this post by Joshua Bloch on [defensive copying of fields](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2).